# Type Refinement

Tags: scala, types

How can I make the following work?

```
trait T {
  type I <: T
  def apply(i: I): I
}

class Foo[T0 <: T](t: T0) {
  def bar(x: T0) = t(x)
}
implicit def tofoo[T0 <: T](t: T0) = new Foo(t)
```

The `bar` line yields the error:

```
type mismatch; found : x.type (with underlying type T0) required: Foo.this.t.I
```

(One might argue why pimp and having `bar` doing the same as `apply` in `T`. But it´s because I reduced the problem. In my working code I have a Seq[T] as a parameter of `bar`.)

**EDIT:**

Due to the answer of @AlexeyRomanov I show an example (also reduced from working code) what also should work:

```
trait T {
  type I <: T
  def apply(i: I): I
}

class Foo[T0 <: T { type I = T0 }](val t: T0) {
  def bar(x: T0) = t(x)
  def test = "!"
}

implicit def tofoo[T0 <: T { type I = T0 }](t: T0) = new Foo(t)


trait TA extends T {
  type I = TA
}
case class TB() extends TA {
  def apply(i: I): I = i
}

println(TB().test) // ERROR: value test is not a member of TB
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because it is not sound. Suppose it worked, then we could do this:

```
trait T {
  type I <: T
  def apply(i: I): I
}

class Foo[T0 <: T](t: T0) {
  def bar(x: T0) = t(x)
}

class TA extends T {
    type I = TB
    def apply(i: I): I = i
}

class TB extends T {
    type I = T
    def apply(i: I): I = i
}

val ta = new TA
val foo = new Foo(ta)
foo.bar(ta) // calls ta(ta)
```

But `ta.apply` expects an element of type `TB`, not `TA`!

So, basically, the code you wrote does not represent the type relationships you have in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo[T0 <: T {type I = T0}](val t: T0) { 
  def bar(x: T0) = t(x) 
}

implicit def tofoo[T0 <: T {type I = T0}](t: T0) = new Foo(t)
```

Comment: I am confused right now: Am I right that your solution states `T0.I = T0`? But what if `I` should be a subtype of `T` as denoted in `trait T`? (Perhaps I haven´t set that clear in my question) Is it still possible?

Comment: Then that's what you should require: `T {type I >: T0}`

Comment: If the only requirement is that `I` be a subtype of `T` then obviously it's not possible: that's why your original definition doesn't compile. Just consider definitions `trait TA extends T` and `class TB() extends T { type I = TA; def apply(x: TA) = x}`. What should `new Foo[TB](new TB).bar(new TB)` do?

Comment: I want to ensure that the parameter `x` of `bar` has the same underlying type `I` as `t` in `Foo`. So the types of some `T` for `Foo` and of some other `T` for the `bar` parameter can be different, but their underlying `I` has to be the same. E.g. two subclasses `Tb` and `Tc` of my above `Ta` have the same `I` but are different types while wrapping in `Foo`.

Comment: Well, if `x` is just some `T` with a given underlying `I`, then `t(x)` doesn't make sense.